# Woocommerce updating shipping method on address change on a checkout page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

We recently started using distance based shipping for certain products. I have separated the shipping method from the review-order (picture of the design below). I basically just moved `wc_cart_totals_shipping_html();` to form-checkout and it worked fine until we started using distance based shipping. I noticed that when the address is updated the price in review-order is updated but not the shipping method. Only after page refresh it would sync up.

I understand that the problem comes from AJAX not refreshing the part that I moved out but not sure how to fix it. The furthest I got with this was finding a thread with similar issue https://wordpress.org/support/topic/update-shipping-methods-in-checkout-via-ajax/. The method here is technically working (the shipping method is updating) but it causes another set of strange things that I could not figure out and I do not completely understand what it does. Namely I have sectioned the checkout process into sections and each of them can be opened as a dropdown through some jQuery. But after the "solution" above, I could not target the HTML elements brought in with JS anymore.

My solution before the "solution" above:

form-checkout.php

```
if ( WC()->cart->needs_shipping() && WC()->cart->show_shipping() ) : ?>

  <table class="checkout-shipping-table"> 
    <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>
  </table>
                    
<?php endif; ?>
```

[image: Checkout page]

Comment: This should help you out to trigger needed event - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/342148/list-of-js-events-in-the-woocommerce-frontend

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 // file name : shipping-order-review.php
 //eg : checkout/shipping-order-review.php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping' ); ?>

    <?php wc_cart_totals_shipping_html(); ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_shipping' ); ?>

//Function.php

// hook into the fragments in AJAX and add our new table to the group
add_filter('woocommerce_update_order_review_fragments', 'amitg_order_fragments_split_shipping', 10, 1);
function amitg_order_fragments_split_shipping($order_fragments) {

    ob_start();
    amitg_woocommerce_order_review_shipping_split();
    $websites_depot_woocommerce_order_review_shipping_split = ob_get_clean();
    $order_fragments['.woocommerce-shipping-totals'] = $websites_depot_woocommerce_order_review_shipping_split;
    return $order_fragments;

}

    // We'll get the template that just has the shipping options that we need for the new table
    function amitg_woocommerce_order_review_shipping_split( $deprecated = false ) {
        wc_get_template( 'checkout/shipping-order-review.php', array( 'checkout' => WC()->checkout() ) );
    }
```